# Encoding SLD files

Tags: geoserver, c#, sld, geoserver-rest-api

I am creating a SLD file and uploading it though the REST API using C#. This SLD file contains some danish characters, but the end result turns out bad. For a test I save the xml file to disk before sending it.

Here is my code

```
WebResponse response = null;
WebRequest request = null;

request = WebRequest.Create(sldUrl);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_userName, _password);
request.ContentType = "application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml";
request.Method = "PUT";

sldDocument.Save("c:\\test.sld");

byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sldDocument.ToString());
Stream reqstr = request.GetRequestStream();
reqstr.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
reqstr.Close();

response = request.GetResponse();

response.Close();
```

The local file contains this

```
<Title>Trådhegn</Title>
```

But in the SLD file on the server it looks like this

```
<sld:Title>TrÃ¥dhegn</sld:Title>
```

I tried reading the stream as Unicode but that gives me this error

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 2; The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
```

Im running geoserver 2.7 on a windows machine

Comment: The second error is usually what you see if you have a BOM character set. Have you set the UTF-8 encoding with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>?

Comment: Yes I have set that.

Comment: Then make sure bom is turned off on your editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work with changing the encoding to ISO-8859-1

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(sldDocument.ToString());
```

Not sure why but it works..

Comment: This may help you understand (read answers and links): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864272/understanding-text-encoding-in-net